# Regex split string on custom delimiter up to specific word

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to parse some strings for an application I made.
I would like to split on commas only when they are followed by an asterisk up to and not including the first occurrence of a specific word, let's say "CONDITION". So, for example string: `!Example,Value,1,*SPLIT_THIS=True,*AND_THIS=True,*CONDITION=Something/ELSE:!Example,Value,2,*DONT_SPLIT=True,*AND_NOT_THIS=True,*CONDITION=SomethingElse/ELSE:False`

Should be split like:

`["!Example,Value,1",
"*SPLIT_THIS=True",
"*AND_THIS=True", "*CONDITION=Something/ELSE:!Example,Value,2,*DONT_SPLIT=True,*AND_NOT_THIS=True,*CONDITION=SomethingElse/ELSE:False"]`

So, there may be more "CONDITION"s in there and more comma-asterisks, but I only want to split until the first occurrence of "CONDITION". I have tried a positive look-ahead like `(?=(CONDITION))` or `(?=CONDITION)` with `',\*'` to split on commas followed by an asterisk (without including the asterisk), but I cannot seem to find the right one. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: You need to do it in several steps, I Ido not think a single regex can be used to achieve this.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/rLvOsP, and let know if it works for you.

Comment: Almost worked! The last part of the string (the second CONDITION part) should begin with an asterisk but it doesn't in this example. Thank you for the quick reply, i was being stubborn thinking I could make it work with a single expression but apparently it's not possible. An initial split does  the trick just fine.

Comment: Oops. I see an older link here. I forked and revamped my suggestion. I will post once I recover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply specific logic here since a one regex solution is not possible (we'd need an infinite width lookbehind to check if there is `CONDITION` somewhere to the left of the current location, and it is possible with PyPi regex module only).

Here is a possible solution:

```
import re
s = '!Example,Value,1,*SPLIT_THIS=True,*AND_THIS=True,*CONDITION=Something/ELSE:!Example,Value,2,*DONT_SPLIT=True,*AND_NOT_THIS=True,*CONDITION=SomethingElse/ELSE:False'
x = re.search(r"\*(CONDITION|MOREOPTIONS)", s)
res = []
if x:
    res = re.findall(r"(?:^|\*)[^*]+(?=,|$)", s[:x.start(1)])
    res.append(s[x.start(1):])

print(res)
# => ['!Example,Value,1', '*SPLIT_THIS=True', '*AND_THIS=True', 
     'CONDITION=Something/ELSE:!Example,Value,2,*DONT_SPLIT=True,*AND_NOT_THIS=True,*CONDITION=SomethingElse/ELSE:False']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/j2Zafe)

**Details**:

- `re.search(r"\*(CONDITION|MOREOPTIONS)", s)` - finds the first occurrence of the `CONDITION` (add more `|`-seaprated options if needed)
- `re.findall(r"(?:^|\*)[^*]+(?=,|$)", s[:x.start(1)])` - if there is a match, find all non-overlapping occurrences in the string before the `CONDITION` that match:

  - `(?:^|\*)` - start of string or `*`
  - `[^*]+` - 1 or more chars other than `*`
  - `(?=,|$)` - require a `,` or end of string without consuming them
- `res.append(s[x.start(1):])`  - just appends the part with and after `CONDITION`.

Comment: Thank you for the ultra-fast reply, the clear explanation and the pointer to the infinite width lookbehind! I will do some follow up reading on that.

Comment: Here is a regex that you may use in PyPi `regex.split` - [`(?<!,\*CONDITION=.*?),(?=\*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%2c%5c*CONDITION%3d.*%3f%29%2c%28%3f%3d%5c*%29&i=!Example%2cValue%2c1%2c*SPLIT_THIS%3dTrue%2c*AND_THIS%3dTrue%2c*CONDITION%3dSomething%2fELSE%3a!Example%2cValue%2c2%2c*DONT_SPLIT%3dTrue%2c*AND_NOT_THIS%3dTrue%2c*CONDITION%3dSomethingElse%2fELSE%3aFalse). However, I am not sure PyPi is that stable as .NET regex engine.

Comment: Thank you again for the alternate solution! This will go in a production server, so the solution you provided is rock-solid! I will experiment with PyPi though! :)